# Google Indexing API: Permission denied. Failed to verify the URL ownership

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-indexing-api

I've looked through all of the other threads on this and unfortunately they still haven't resolved my issue, so I'm hoping you can help! I'm trying to use Google's Indexing API via Google App Script. So far I've:

Followed the documentation step-by-step; created a service account, connected my app script to my GC project and added my client email as an **owner** of a search console property.

I've also included my app script manifest file to include the following oauthScopes:

```
    "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
```

Most of the 403 errors I've read about are resolved by adding the client email as an owner of a Search Console property, but in my case, that hasn't resolved the issue. Happy to provide more details if needed! :)

Here's my Google App Script:

```
var Json = {
    "private_key": "###",
    "client_email": "###",
    "client_id": "###",
    "user_email": "###"
};


/**
 * Authorizes and makes a request to the Google+ API.
 */
function run() {

  var requestBody = {
       "url":"http://testymctestface.com",
       "type":"URL_UPDATED"
}

   var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        },
        'payload': JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };

        var service = getService();
        var url = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
        Logger.log(response);

}

/**
 * Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
 */
function reset() {

  var service = getService();
  service.reset();
}

/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Indexing API')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setPrivateKey(Json.private_key)
      .setIssuer(Json.client_email)
      .setSubject(Json.user_email)
      .setClientId(Json.client_id)

      // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to complete
      // the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scope and additional Google-specific parameters.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing')
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force')
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}

/**
 * Handles the OAuth callback.
 */
function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied');
  }
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/core-errors#api-FORBIDDEN). You should verify the url in your requestBody as your own. Also `Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` should be `Bearer ' + getService().getAccessToken()`

Comment: Thanks for this - appreciate you replying! How do you mean verify the url in the requestBody as my own?

Comment: In the search console, the url should've been added and verified https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/176793

Comment: I've verified those urls. In changing the access tokens, I'm now receiving the error 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. '

Answer (score 8):

Did you add your client email in the new Search Console, or the [old Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?)? "Owner" was not an option for me in the new one (only "Full" or "Restricted"), I had to go to the old one to add another owner.

Comment: FYI: Remove the owner which you just added. Then click on the three dots next to an owner and then on 'Manage Property Owners'. Now add the new owner again under the property, and that's that - cat in a hat.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the old search console allows to add "Owners". The new one only has "Restricted"/"Not Restricted" :( I'd like to cross-link the Google Help thread: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4763732?hl=en&authuser=1

Answer (score -1):

you have to change this line

`'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`

in

`'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ service.getAccessToken()`